# How to remotely access a LAN network (embedded) device without port forwarding?

Tags: android, embedded, remote-access, portforwarding, mqtt

I've looked around SO and haven't found exactly the answer I'm looking for, so please forgive me if this is a duplicate. If so, please direct me to the answer. Thanks.

I've got an embedded sensor/actuator system with wifi connectivity to my LAN.

What are possible software/protocol solutions so i can communicate with and control it remotely, from outside my network with an iPhone/Android (i.e. via 3G/4G) and/or a remote PC?

i don't want to have to configure my router for port forwarding.

Here are a few other considerations:

- embedded processing platform is pretty limited (i.e. it's not an ARM)
- security is important (i.e. don't want others to be able to gain access easily)
- scalability - if this project goes commercial, scalability of this model to many, many users is important
- user simplicity (i.e. no messy configuration reqs for the end user)

I've heard a little about MQTT, which looks like it might be a solution, but I'm not sure about security. Any thoughts on that?

Any other options that are free?

Thanks a lot, Brian

Comment: @ChrisStratton, Thank you so much for your help and input. I really appreciate it. Still learning about how to properly participate here on SO.

Comment: Another simple solution might be an HTTPS-based relay / reverse proxy like Pagekite.com or Yaler.net (disclosure: I'm a founder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use MQTT you will need a broker that is accessible from both inside the network and outside.

So assuming you host your own broker you will need to set up port forwarding to allow access to it from the mobile device. The other option would be host the broker on a cloud service.

Security can be handled by doing MQTT over SSL and using client side certificate authentication so only your client application can connect to broker.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the system working inside LAN, you could use a package such as wamp running on a networked PC to act as a server and set up an external facing network interface which can handle security. Then use the wamp server to forward to the embedded device when required through PHP etc. That would save working out how to directly communicate securely with an embedded device.

I can't suggest anything more useful on the amount of information given